# Doing calculation in PowerPivot (Excel 2010) based on two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, powerpivot, power-query

I am on Excel 2010 with PowerQuery and PowerPivot add-ins installed.

I have two tables, where:

- Table1 has amounts denominated in different currencies.
- Table2 has conversion rates (exchange rates).

I am trying add a column in Table1 to show converted amount besides amount in original currency.

Background (if needed):
PowerQuery is used to feed Table1 from multiple CSV files in a folder for a dashboard. Since PQuery cannot do calculations therefore I am doing so using PPivot.

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution myself (please update if there a better way)

> =[ForeignAmount]*RELATED(fxtable[ConversionRate])